# Сервер отдает одно и то же содержимое во всех подключаемых файлах index-страницы

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Вот так выглядит код сервера

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('app listening on port 3000') 
});
```

`index.ejs` на текущий момент - обычная html-страничка, в ней подключается скрипт `app.js` (файл лежит в папке public). 
При переходе по адресу `localhost:3000`, сервер возвращает содержимое `index.ejs` . Проблема со скриптом app.js. он подгружается, но его содержимое такое же, как и у `index.ejs.` Как сделать, чтобы сервер отдавал именно содержимое скрипта?